# rawurl encode problem

Tags: php

i am using `rawurlencode($url_variable)` while passing to a script..
when i receive the variable in the script ,before passing this variable to mysql ,i was doing `mysql_real_escape_string` . now the problem is like when there is a variable like

`$url_variable = "Off-St.Mark's-Road"`  ...after i do mysql_real_escape_string it become slike

Off-St.Mark\\'s-Road    .

which is creating a problem in mysql query ...

how i get over this...rawurlencode is necessary to pass variables to the script and i want to do mysql_real_escape_string to make the data safe...

Comment: can you be more precise about the problem it's creating in your mysql query?

Comment: Off-St.Mark\\'s-Road in query was creating problem.it was not finding proper results.magic_quotes_gpc was on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned on on your server, try this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
   $text = stripslashes($your_var);
}

$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

Comment: I have a small doubt..does rawurlencode add \ to escape the quotes?

Comment: @pradeep: I don't think so, most likely you have `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on.

Comment: okie..thanks for the help...i found this script ...hope its useful for others

function sanitize($input){
    if(is_array($input)){
        foreach($input as $k=>$i){
            $output[$k]=sanitize($i);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $input=stripslashes($input);
        }
        $output=mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }

    return $output;
}